# How to prove that this operator is a projector?

Tags: representation-theory

I found an exercise in a book by Bogoliubov. The aim is to prove that a given operator is a projector. C is considered as a Hilbert space with the product of two complex numbers $\langle z, z'\rangle$ being $z^*z'$. We have a set of operators W(z) in CCR(C). By definition they have the these properties:
$$W(0) = id$$
$$W(z)W(z') = W(z+z') e^{i Im(z^* z')}$$
He considers the operator
$$\Pi = \int W(z) e^{-z^*z/2} dx dy$$
and we have to prove that it is a projector.
In a first step he established two relations
$$\Pi W(z) = e^{-z^*z/2} \int W(\zeta) e^{z^* \zeta} e^{-\zeta^*\zeta/2} dRe \zeta d Im \zeta $$ and
$$ W(z) \Pi= e^{-z^*z/2} \int W(\zeta) e^{z \zeta^*} e^{-\zeta^*\zeta/2} dRe \zeta d Im \zeta $$
Then he writes that we can use these two equalities to show that the set of operators $$\Pi e^{z^*z/2} W(z)\Pi $$ contains only one element and that it is $\Pi$ How can it be proved?
You can read the text in [his book](https://books.google.fr/books?id=lvT1CAAAQBAJ&pg=PA267&lpg=PA267&dq=We%20claim%20that%20the%20operator%20%20%22is%20non-zero.%20Thus%20consider%22&source=bl&ots=1Lj35j784u&sig=ACfU3U0ds4MkTz-4ZzsfSBpWIvU0X1P3bA&hl=fr&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi_pqXoiIDjAhVjmVwKHZumDk4Q6AEwAHoECAEQAQ#v=onepage&q=We%20claim%20that%20the%20operator%20%20%22is%20non-zero.%20Thus%20consider%22&f=false).

Comment: What does $CCR(\Bbb C)$ mean? (Also, you seemed to have edited out the part of your question where you actually ask a question.)

Comment: CCR means canondical commutation relations (here in the Weyl form defined on C). you can find an exemple of such W(z) in this paper: https://www.google.fr/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=2ahUKEwjfuOOEgPbjAhX16eAKHfRcAmAQFjAAegQIBBAC&url=https%3A%2F%2Fhomepage.univie.ac.at%2Freinhold.bertlmann%2Fpdfs%2FT2_Skript_Ch_5.pdf&usg=AOvVaw1bmKVjg8bPHnIhmXcFNShp          here they are the displacement operators D(theta). skip to page 15